# How i can simplify this regular expression

Tags: regex

```
^[0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4} [0-9a-f]{4}$
```

This is the format to validate input string like:

```
a28a 3bef 1b2b 4b49 2e3d 3867 8753 a024 0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generally group repeats at *different* levels. Assuming you want exactly nine four-digit lower-case hex numbers with a single space inbetween each one, it's as simple as something like:

```
^[0-9a-f]{4}( [0-9a-f]{4}){8}$
```

Since you already *know* about the meaning of `[0-9a-f]{4}`, the only thing to explain is the added `( [0-9a-f]{4}){8}`. This is simply a space followed by another four hex digits, with both of those repeated exactly eight times.

If it's *not* exactly nine, you can simply adjust the `{8}` to provide other bounds on the occurrences, such as a range like `{0,12}` or the zero-or-more `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce a bit more by using pattern recursion availlable in [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)

```
^([0-9a-f]{4})(?: (?1)){8}$
```

Where `(?1)` represents the same pattern than group 1 (ie. `[0-9a-f]{4}`)